# Script for deleting old long-ago opened files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to delete files that were not opened for more than 60 days, but they may have been created long before that. I opened the information about last access with `fsutil`, but I don't know which parameter should I use in script.

I already know how to delete old files and I just need to change /d to "data of last access". Here is a standard script for deleting:

```
forfiles /p "C:\Users\...\" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c Del @path" /d -30
```

Comment: `Forfiles` uses the last modified time and date, you cannot configure it to use access or created date and times.

Comment: _N. B.:_ remove the trailing `\ `from the path after `/P` to not escape the following `"`; the mask after `/M` should only be `*` to not exclude files without extension; and you should extend the command after `/C` to `"cmd /C if @isdir == FALSE del @PATH"`...

Comment: Last access time stamps can be disabled. They are disabled by default since Windows Vista/Server 2008.